# Disable taskbar tooltips in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I find they frequently get stuck open if you have a near-full-screen application open.

Is it possible to disable them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open "regedit" as adminstrator.

Navigate to:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
```

Find "ShowInfoTip", right-click and select "Modify" and change the value to "0"

Comment: this is a life saver... I was thinking of going back to windows XP ;)

Comment: This hides *all* tooltips, right? Not just those in the taskbar? If so, it's worth making that explicitly clear in your answer.

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me. I double-checked the key and value and they are as mentioned. If I leave my mouse over some pinned programs on the taskbar, the tooltip always show. I run Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, SP1.

Comment: Didn't work for me, either, on Windows 7 pro x64.

Comment: something had re-enabled this undesirable feature (keeps covering things you want to click)

Answer (score 19):

You might be experiencing this issue, described on Microsoft's Q/A forum:

[Why does the tooltip display on taskbar icons when I am not hovering my cursor on them?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/why-does-the-tooltip-display-on-taskbar-icons-when/e47fd1ca-35c8-408d-88f8-94c0a1969a6b?msgId=785e8e9a-3028-4149-9748-e22e5d7d0b12)

The suggestion there is to make sure your video drivers are up to date. For a momentary fix, you can try:

1. Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-clicking on a tile.
2. If that doesn't work, try killing `dwm.exe`.

Comment: So far, shift-right-click has been working for me. I prefer to do this every once in a while rather than completely disable the tooltips.

Comment: This also works in Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

Click Start>Run, type Gpedit.msc. Under User Configuration>Administrative Templates>Start Menu and Taskbar,  enable 'Remove Balloon Tips on Start Menu items'

Comment: Spoke too soon, sorry. This only hides some of the tool tips on the start menu, not all. Boo.

Comment: Solved my problem